# how to create a 3d spatial density map?

Tags: matlab, pixel-density

I have a time-dependent system of varying number of particles (~100k particles). In fact, each particle represents an interaction in a 3D space with a particular strength. Thus, each particle has  (X,Y,Z;w) which is the coordinate plus a weight factor between 0 and 1, showing the strength of interaction in that coordinate. 
Here http://pho.to/9Ztti  I have uploaded 10 real-time snapshots of the system, with particles are represented as reddish small dots; the redder the dot, the stronger the interaction is.

The question is: how one can produce a 3D (spatial) density map of these particles, preferably in Matlab or Origin Pro 9 or [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/)? Is there a way to, say, take the average of these images based on the red-color intensity in [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/)?

Since I have the numerical data for particles (X,Y,Z;w)  I can analyze those data in other software as well. So, you are welcome to suggest any other analytical approach/software

Any ideas/comments are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in 3D continuous space and your dataset is just a list of the 3d positions of each particle interaction, it sounds like you want to make a 4D weighted histogram.  You'll have to chop the 3d space into bins and sum the weighted points in each bin over time, then plot the results in a single 3d plot where color represents the summed weighted interactions over time.

Heres an example with randomly generated particle interactions:`

```
%% Create dataSet of random particle interations in 3d space
for i=1:5000
    if i == 1
        dataSet = [rand()*100 rand()*100 rand()*100 rand() i];
    else
        dataSet(i,:) = [rand()*100 rand()*100 rand()*100 rand() i];
    end
end
% dataSet = [x y z interactionStrength imageNumber]

xLimits = [min(dataSet(:,1)) max(dataSet(:,1))];
yLimits = [min(dataSet(:,2)) max(dataSet(:,2))];
zLimits = [min(dataSet(:,3)) max(dataSet(:,3))];

binSize = 10; % Number of bins to split each spatial dimention into
binXInterval = (xLimits(2)-xLimits(1))/binSize;
binYInterval = (yLimits(2)-yLimits(1))/binSize;
binZInterval = (zLimits(2)-zLimits(1))/binSize;

histo = [];
for i=xLimits(1)+(binSize/2):binXInterval:xLimits(2) + (binSize/2)
    for j=yLimits(1)+(binSize/2):binYInterval:yLimits(2) + (binSize/2)
        for k=zLimits(1)+(binSize/2):binZInterval:zLimits(2) + (binSize/2)
            %% Filter out particle interactions found within the current spatial bin
            idx = find((dataSet(:,1) > (i - binSize)) .* (dataSet(:,1) < i));
            temp = dataSet(idx,:);
            idx = find((temp(:,2) > (j - binSize)) .* (temp(:,2) < j));
            temp = temp(idx,:);
            idx = find((temp(:,3) > (k - binSize)) .* (temp(:,3) < k));
            temp = temp(idx,:);
            %% Add up all interaction strengths found within this bin
            histo = [histo; i j k sum(temp(:,4))];
        end
    end
end
%% Remove bins with no particle interactions
idx = find(histo(:,4)>0);
histo = histo(idx,:);
numberOfImages = max(dataSet(:,5));
%% Plot result
PointSizeMultiplier = 100000;
scatter3(histo(:,1).*binXInterval + xLimits(1),histo(:,2).*binYInterval + yLimits(1),histo(:,3).*binZInterval + zLimits(1),(histo(:,4)/numberOfImages)*PointSizeMultiplier,(histo(:,4)/numberOfImages));
colormap hot;
%Size and color represent the average interaction intensity over time
```

4D histogram made from 10000 randomly generated particle interactions.  Each axis divided into 10 bins.  Size and color represent summed particle interactions in each bin over time:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your system can handle the matrix in Matlab it could be as easy as

```
A = mean(M, 4);
```

Assuming `M` holds the 4D compilation of your images then `A` would be your map.

Comment: It definitely can be imported into matlab as matrix. But, what is `M`?? ("`M` holds the 4D compilation of images..") What do you do mean by "4D compilation of an image"?!

Comment: I was assuming you had a 4D matrix with the work each `M(:,:,:,i)`holding a 3D image of your red dots.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a 3D scatter (bubble) plot, with variable circle/bubble sizes, proportional to the intensity of your particle.

Here is a simulated example:

```
N = 1e4;       % number of particles

X = randn(N,1);          % randomly generated coordinates
Y = 2*randn(N,1);
Z = 0.5*randn(N,1);
S = exp(-sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2));  % bubble size vector

scatter3(X,Y,Z,S*200)
```

[image: Scaterplot]
end

Here I have randomly generated values for X, Y and Z, while S is reversely proportional to the distance from the center of the cloud.

In your case, if we assume that the (X,Y,Z,w) values are stored in a 2D array called ***Particles***, it would be:

```
X = Particles(:,1);
Y = Particles(:,2);
Z = Particles(:,3);
S = Particles(:,4);
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: That's a good idea. But, instead of varying bubbles sizes, I think I prefer to vary the transparency of bubbles. Do you know how to change the degree of transparency in matlab?